# Adding new electrical outlet to formerly exterior wall, via crawlspace?

Tags: electrical, crawlspace

I have a formerly exterior wall that is now a wall to an enclosed sun porch.  I want to add an electrical outlet there.

The nearest outlet is on a 15 amp circuit and is located about 2 feet away, on a perpendicular wall.

My thought was to use the crawlspace to connect 2 feet to the new outlet, which would avoid drywall removal and patching.  However, I don't know if exterior walls are accessible from the crawlspace or not (the sun porch is on a slab, no crawl space).

Any advice?  I plan to also research the specifics of adding a new electrical connection, but I wanted to resolve the question of where the line would go, first.

Comment: My advice would be to crawl into the crawl space to see if you can get access to the bottom of the wall and if there's wood or s solid concrete where you want to run your wiring. Take a couple of clear, focused pics while you're under there, especially if you're not sure, then you can post them for people to give you advice, if you're not sure.

Comment: Thank you, I did go down there but frankly I am not sure what a bottom of a wall looks like.  I saw the joists and, I guess, subfloor, but not sure how to identify if a wall is at a particular place (or whether it is over the concrete sides of the foundation).  Any advice on that?  Failing that, yes I will go take some photos and share.  Appreciate your time.

Comment: Photos will help. Someone will likely download your pic, draw on it, then upload it as an answer pointing out what's what.

Comment: You may have to do some measuring if it's not clear where the walls are from the bottom side.  Try to identify some "landmarks" that you can use as reference points and see if you can measure from those to where the call should be.  If it's a non-structural wall you may have nothing but some nails (along with all the others) that attach the wall to the subfloor.

Comment: Not sure about your house, but in mine the bottom plate of all the exterior walls are accessible from the crawlspace. That may be difficult to tell because the exterior wall was probably built onto the floor of the house, so the bottom plate of the wall is not visible.  A typical buildup, from bottom to top would be block wall->sill plate ->floor joists->sub-floor->wall.  I left of non-structural components such as termite shield, etc.